# Custom Service Hooks using ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to implement custom service hooks and this is what I did so far...

global.asax

```
public override IServiceRunner<TRequest> CreateServiceRunner<TRequest>(ActionContext actionContext)
{           
    return new MyServiceRunner<TRequest>(this, actionContext);
}
```

MyServiceRunner.cs

```
public class MyServiceRunner<T> : ServiceRunner<T> {
    public override void OnBeforeExecute(IRequestContext requestContext, TRequest request) {
      // Called just before any Action is executed
    }

    public override object OnAfterExecute(IRequestContext requestContext, object response) {
      // Called just after any Action is executed, you can modify the response returned here as well
    }

    public override object HandleException(IRequestContext requestContext, TRequest request, Exception ex) {
      // Called whenever an exception is thrown in your Services Action
    }
}
```

In global.asax, it is showing an error "Constructor MyServiceRunner has 0 parameter(s) but is invoked with 2 argument(s)" for return statement.

Can some one help me... I definitely need to use actionContext if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a constructor, it should be:

```
public class MyServiceRunner<T> : ServiceRunner<T> 
{
  public MyServiceRunner(IAppHost appHost, ActionContext actionContext) 
      : base(appHost, actionContext) {}

  public override void OnBeforeExecute(IRequestContext requestContext, 
     TRequest request) {
    // Called just before any Action is executed
  }

  public override object OnAfterExecute(IRequestContext requestContext, 
     object response) {
      // Called just after any Action is executed, you can modify the response
  }

  public override object HandleException(IRequestContext requestContext, 
      TRequest request, Exception ex) {
    // Called whenever an exception is thrown in your Services Action
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you once again. Since this is my first ServiceStack project, you suggestions are really valuable.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful.  I was going around in circles because the documentation (https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api#custom-hooks) fails to include the constructor.